# gedit 3.18.3 accels in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, gedit

I like to have the time/date entered with F5 and I'd like to try to make this work in gedit.
I found some dox that say to edit a file .config/gedit/accels
I've done this but the shortcuts don't work. Here's what I added to accels:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/GeditTimePluginActions/InsertDateAndTime" "F5")
```

Anyone have ideas on how to make gedit 3.18.3 use the settings in .config/gedit/accels?

Comment: Nevermind. I see that gedit is marked as unmaintained and is seeking maintainers . I switched to geany and setting up F5 for the date/time is trivial (Preferences/Keyboard/Keybindings.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I see that gedit is marked as unmaintained and is seeking maintainers . I switched to geany and setting up F5 for the date/time is trivial (Preferences/Keyboard/Keybindings.